# Chrome - how to customize the "add bookmark" popup

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome, bookmarks

I am looking for a way to change and customize the standard popup window that comes up in Chrome whenever one wants to add a bookmark.

This is the window I'm talking about:

[image]

I've searched through dozens of extensions and they all relate to managing the bookmarks in Chrome, but not related to *adding* a bookmark, as described here.

Is there a way of customizing this feature with an extension or some settings??...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That dialog is at a level where extensions cannot modify it. This cannot be done.

Comment: Ok, got it. Even "no" is an answer. :) Thanks!